# JSONDecodeError when parsing through data, works half the time?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Heyo, I've been working on this code:

```
import requests as r
import datetime
import openpyxl
import json
import matplotlib #i was gonna use this for graphing later lol

from openpyxl.chart.axis import DateAxis
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference, Series, LineChart

#i dont thinks we have to do it this way, i just saw that this is how the guy on stackoverflow was doing it and didnt argue lol
try:
        from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
except ImportError:
        from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
        from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string


myname = input('Enter your name: ')

def do_the_work(myname):

    userLink = 'https://api.faceit.com/users/v1/nicknames/'+myname #Inputting the name given here to get the UUID of the user
    
    print("Getting user . . . this may take a while")
    
    reqUserLink = r.get(userLink).json() #requesting the link's JSON data
    print("UUID Found; ",str(reqUserLink['payload']['id']))
    reqUserList = []
    reqUserList.append(str(reqUserLink['payload']['id'])) #adding it to our own list because python HATES nested stuff
    print(reqUserList)
    userStatsLink = ""
    userStatsLink = f"https://api.faceit.com/stats/v1/stats/time/users/{reqUserList[0]}/games/csgo"
    print(userStatsLink)
    params = {"page": 0, "size": 30} #we have to do this because the data prevents us from having more than 30 matches a page

    matches = [] #creating our own dictionary to grab only relevant data from the matches
    totalRankedM = 1 #showing ranked matches (aka matches that have an ELO value)
    
    while True:
        reqStatsPage = r.get(userStatsLink, params=params) #Requesting
        statsPageJSON = reqStatsPage.json()
        print(statsPageJSON)
        for match in statsPageJSON:
            elo = match.get("elo")  #elo variable of the stats
            if elo is not None:  #checking if elo does exist (Faceit removes this parameter from matches that have no elo)
                matches.append({ #adding them to our own list with the relevant data wanted
                    'match_id': match["matchId"],
                    'played_on': match["date"],
                    'map': match["i1"],
                    'elo': match["elo"]
                })
                totalRankedM = totalRankedM + 1 #each time we have a match that counts elo, it is a ranked match

            else:
                matches.append({
                    'match_id': match["matchId"],
                    'played_on': match["date"],
                    'map': match["i1"],
                    'elo': ''  #just putting nothing tbh, we replace this later to "No elo recorded" but i like the freedom
                })
        if len(statsPageJSON) < params['size']: #check if we went thru all the pages
            break

        params['page'] += 1 #changing page

    print(f'Total number of matches: {len(matches)}')  #print the total number of matches
    print(f'Total number of ranked matches: {totalRankedM}') #print total ranked matches

    matches.reverse() #since we start at the top of the pages aka most recent matches and go down from there, we reverse this to make it easier for the excel sheet graph so it's in order

    workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.active

    worksheet.append(['Match ID', 'Played On', 'Map', 'ELO', 'Total Ranked Matches']) #those are the columns
    for match in matches: #adding the data from the matches=[] list to the sheet
        worksheet.append([match['match_id'], match['played_on'], match['map'], match['elo']])

    worksheet["E2"].value = totalRankedM
    worksheet["F1"].value = 'To view the game room of a specific match, simply use this link: https://www.faceit.com/en/csgo/room/REPLACE THIS WITH MATCHID/scoreboard'

    for cell in worksheet['D']: #to make it pretty in the excel sheet and get rid of errors, we convert the strings that are numbers to actual numbers in the sheet (excel considers them strings, so it throws an error when its a string number)
        if isinstance(cell.value, str):
            try:
                number = int(cell.value)
                cell.data_type = 'n'
                cell.value = number
            except ValueError:
                pass #just ignoring if we can't make it a number

    for cell in worksheet['B']: #the data we are given for the dates are in unix so we just convert
        if isinstance(cell.value, int):
            date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(cell.value / 1000)
            date_str = date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            cell.value = date_str

    for column_cells in worksheet.columns: #this is just to make each cell size fit the length of the text in it
        new_column_length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells)
        new_column_letter = (get_column_letter(column_cells[0].column))
        if new_column_length > 0:
            worksheet.column_dimensions[new_column_letter].width = new_column_length*1.23




    #and we save the final product xd
    workbook.save('matches.xlsx')


do_the_work(myname)
#fancy stuff
print("\n")
print("\n")
print("\n")
print("You may now look at the excel sheet.")
```

that basically

- lets you input a name
- uses faceit's API calls to get the data from said account, gets the UUID (because this is the only way you can see the stats page of a user in the link),
- adds that UUID to our list (i think I made it that way when trying to figure out why I was getting the error but that part still works fine) (i think lol, still had the same error before it)
- then it adds that UUID to the stats link so we can parse through it
- grabs the relevant data and adds it to our own list
- prints that list
- adds it to an excel sheet

Now the weird part of this is that when I try to run the program, it works for the first time and loads everything correctly and adds it to the excel sheet.

But then I want to do it again with the same username (it should just overwrite) and then it stops halfway through it to show me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SAM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\SAM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 7 column 10 (char 107)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Desktop\elo-scrape\test3.py", line 111, in <module>
    do_the_work(myname)
  File "C:\Users\SAM\Desktop\elo-scrape\test3.py", line 43, in do_the_work
    statsPageJSON = reqStatsPage.json()
  File "C:\Users\SAM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 7 column 10 (char 107)
```

This specific account I am loading the data from has a total of 1605 ranked matches for context
But then I try to do it with my own account (328 ranked matches) over and over and it works over and over.

Does it just stop working when we have a huge amount of data? If so what way i could improve this code? I've been spending a while trying to fix it and I'm out of ideas which is why I'm here

Comment: Please post all code and error messages as plain text, directly in the question.  Don't make us click on external links, and don't make us re-type code from an image.

Comment: Apologies,i will fix that.

Comment: My first guess is that you should verify that the request was successful before calling `reqStatsPage.json()`.  If the request was unsuccessful in some way, then there very likely won't be any json in the response, and `.json()` will throw an error.

Comment: You were right! I completely forgot that i could check wether we were getting good responses from the link, i just assumed that since it was printing, it was working.
The issue is that I am doing too many requests (I am not sure on how to put your comment as the answer)